# Canonical way to reference Elements

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

Is there a canonical way to set an ID—or other searchable, persistent data attribute—on Elements in Google Docs, such that I can easily refer back to it later? I'm looking for something equivalent to `getElementById` in javascript. Almost all examples I've seen, including Google's own docs, seem to reference objects by searching for text strings or inserting new strings.

I've found one reference in the NamedRanges class to a [`getId`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/named-range#getId()) function, but I can't find any place to *set* that ID. I do see the [`setAttributes`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/element#setattributesattributes) function on Elements but that seems to apply only for pre-defined attribute types. I haven't tested that, though.

In case it's relevant: my interest is in automatically creating a document from a Google Sheet and populating based on the current values in the sheet. I'd like to assign specific Elements individual IDs so I can easily retrieve the Element and replace the text if the values in the sheet change later on.

Comment: No there is nothing like that.  It's pretty difficult to learn how to navigate a document.  I sometimes wonder if that was the goal because it could not have been much better.

Comment: I create documents by just hardwiring the text into the code.  It may not be as user friendly but it works for me and that's all I care about.

Comment: @Cooper - See my answer below; turns out this is possible.

Comment: Hey thanks for pointing that out.  When I first started with Google Docs I don't believe that they had named ranges. Perhaps I just missed them.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out that this is possible using NamedRanges, I just didn't read carefully enough.

> Note: All the following examples are working off [this Google doc](https://docs.google.com/document/d/110oPIjgaRxqum8ilcPGcsBdmLZRyIw5l_M28v-AoRiI/edit). You can make a copy and select "Script Editor" from the Tools menu to see the code.

You can assign named ranges pretty easily using Apps Script. The below code looks through the doc for `[[TITLE]]` and `[[ABSTRACT]]` and assigns named ranges to those chunks. Note that in the aforelinked doc I put them in a table to avoid issues with partial ranges.

```
function assignNamedRanges() {
  const doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  const body = doc.getBody();
  
  const placeholders = ["title", "abstract"];

  placeholders.forEach(p => {
    const rangeBuilder = doc.newRange();
    const text = body.findText("[[" + p.toUpperCase() + "]]");
    rangeBuilder.addElement(text.getElement());
    doc.addNamedRange(p, rangeBuilder.build());
  });
}
```

Once you assigned them, you can update the range to something else in a separate function:

```
function updateNamedRanges() {
  const doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  const body = doc.getBody();

  const title = doc.getNamedRanges("title")[0];
  const abstract = doc.getNamedRanges("abstract")[0];

  title.getRange().getRangeElements()[0].getElement().asText().setText("Bob");
  abstract.getRange().getRangeElements()[0].getElement().asText().setText("I like pancakes");
}
```

Note that NamedRanges are persistent, and the *multiple NamedRange instances can have the same name*. This means that if you run the first function four times, you'll have eight named ranges. You can make a convenience function to clear all those out pretty easily:

```
function clearNamedRanges() {
  DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getNamedRanges().forEach(r => {
    r.remove();
  })
}
```

Comment: Wow that's a lot nicer and using elements.  Thanks again.  I guess it's time to go read the documentation again

Answer (score 1):

So I been checking the documentation about [`elements`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/docs#structure_of_a_document) for Google Docs in AppScript and it seems that some of them can be modified but not as freely as it looks as noted in the documentation:

> Elements shown in bold can be inserted; non-bold elements can only be manipulated in place.

I tried checking with [`setAttributes`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/element#setattributesattributes) as you mentioned however the attributes itself can only be from a document elements like: TEXT, PARAGRAPH, TABLE, ETC, this elements can't receive an ID as there is not method to insert an specific ID as you are requiring, most of the values that can be inserted are specific element attributes like: Font size, Font family, etc.

Comment: elements in google docs are sort of like rich text in spreadsheets where you get access to a string with beginning and ending indexes.  It's a pain I think.  They need less brainiacs at google and more normal iq'd folks.   Thanks for the answer.

Comment: I just realized you a googlite.

Comment: @Cooper https://www.linkedin.com/in/eykanal/ :) We're everywhere!